# Is there any clear downside to regularly keeping potential jobs in the pipeline during this crisis?

Tags: interviewing

I am a software developer with a company that does a bunch of software for various downtown management services. However, with coronavirus emptying downtowns, I am not sure whether governments are going to continue paying for our services. We are very well established and have tons of cash in the bank, but that doesn't mean jobs will be protected.

I can easily see a lot of "cash efficient" startups getting slaughtered by this coronavirus because of all the investment drying up and the economy generally going down the tubes in general.

I have a resume that lets me get Amazon and Google interviews, but can never get past that final tech interview, so I am largely relegated to enterprise development. With those, I can usually get past the tech interview 60% of the time.

Because whether I pass the tech interview is basically 50/50 and the competition is likely to get worse (putting my tech interviewing skills at maybe a 20% pass) and a prolonged slump would eliminate a lot of demand for the services my company provides, I am wondering how viable it is to just keep interviewing constantly and always have an option available. I would prefer to stay, but I know that it may not be my choice.

I currently work from home due to the virus and am one the developers trusted to offline and online when I please as I always get my work done, so interviewing even once a day would be feasible. I am just wondering whether word gets around of this or whether companies blacklist people who decline offers.

Thanks.

Comment: So what you want to do is keep getting offers from companies, prolong not accepting them as long as possible but without ever really planning to take them, just holding on to them as contingency?

Comment: @TymoteuszPaul basically, as my Big O skills are poor, so I want to have more runway than those who are better than I am at interviewing.

Comment: What's 'Big O'?

Comment: @TymoteuszPaul https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation

Comment: Keep in mind that many governments don't arbitrarily cancel contracts with their vendors. You might be wise to ask your supervisor or an executive whether there's anything you personally can do differently to serve your customers in the present crisis. At this point in your career a valuable resume asset is helping customers and your employer weather some real storms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> whether companies blacklist people who decline offers.

Not necessarily blacklist, but they do keep records. Often you're asked if you have ever applied there before as well. So in a competitive market it may backfire, they'll be looking for reasons to filter out candidates.